# PBE Parameters for Compatibility with Java's OpenSSL.encrypt() Function

Tags: java, c, encryption, openssl, pkcs#5

I am attempting to write C code using the openssl libraries to decrypt data that has been encrypted by the Java function [OpenSSL.encrypt()](http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/javadocs/org/apache/commons/ssl/OpenSSL.html).  I know the password, but I have not been able to figure out the parameters for PBE.

I am attempting to use the [EVP_BytesToKey()](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) function, but I don't know which algorithm to use (MD2, MD5, SHA1?) or how many rounds to properly derive the key and iv from the password.  Everywhere I have looked says the Java function is compatible with "openssl enc", but I can't find what parameters it uses either.

I have also looked at PKCS#5, which is what is supposedly implemented, but it doesn't specify a default for algorithm or number of rounds.  Please help!

Edit:
Nevermind, finally found parameters that work - MD5 with one round.